# Prevent whole page from shifting onclick while using horizontally scrollable checkboxes on mobile

Tags: html, css

[JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/BrokenDots/La4x08m9/4/)

I made a horizontally scrollable div using overflow: auto and whitespace: nowrap and put some custom styled checkboxes in it with inline display. The problem I have is that when i scroll to one of the checkboxes towards the end on mobile screens, the whole page shifts and moves out of view. How do I fix it?

```
<html>
  <ul class="ks-cboxtags" id="topic_sec_container" style="display: block;">
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="Study Melbourne" id="checkboxOne" checked=""><label for="checkboxOne">Study Melbourne</label></li>
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="City of Melbourne" id="checkboxTwo"  checked=""><label for="checkboxTwo">City of Melbourne</label></li>
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="Cultural" id="checkboxThree"  checked=""><label for="checkboxThree">Cultural</label></li>
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="Professional development" id="checkboxFour" checked=""><label for="checkboxFour">Professional development</label></li>
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="Employment" id="checkboxFive"  checked=""><label for="checkboxFive">Employment</label></li>
            <li><input name="topic_secondary" type="checkbox" value="Insider Guides" id="checkboxSix"  checked=""><label for="checkboxSix">Click this</label></li>
</ul>
</html>

<style>
/* custom checkboxes */
ul.ks-cboxtags {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}



/* .ks-cboxtags::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
} */

ul.ks-cboxtags li{
    display: inline;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li label{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: none;
    color: var(--blue);
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label {
    /* padding: 8px 12px; */
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}



ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
display: absolute;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this happen only when you select/tap the checkbox(es), or does it shift just by scrolling to them?

Comment: It happens when you click the last two checkboxes, shifts the element and scroll bar to the far right, correct?

Comment: yes, it only happens when you select/tap the last few checkboxes. The shorter the screen-width, the more checkboxes from the right it affects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of effort, I think I figured out why it was happening:

For the input[type="checkbox"], I was using a position of absolute and opacity of 0 to hide the tick box. I replaced it with display: none and it worked.

```
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```